# It seems my laptop can't install Jekyll, again and again install, although I already checked the path environment

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

```
Windows 10 Pro N
ruby 3.0.6p216 [x64-mingw32]
gem 3.2.33
gcc version 13.1.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
GNU Make 4.4.1
```

[image]

I install again and again

```
gem cleanup
gem list jekyll
dir D:/develop/ruby/Ruby30-x64/bin
setx PATH "%PATH%;D:\develop\ruby\Ruby30-x64\bin"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jekyll - command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146249/jekyll-command-not-found)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.